# Vue.js - Unknown custom element: <router-view>

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I'm bit new to Vue.js and I'm trying to implement routing to the application but for some reason I'm facing an issue saying:

> Unknown custom element: `<router-view>` - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

Am i registering the component wrongly? Any help is much appreciated, my code below:

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import AppLayout from './theme/Layout.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  ...AppLayout
})

export { app, router }
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'Vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Category from './theme/Category.vue'
import Login from './theme/Login.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/', component: Category},
    {path: '/login', component: Login}
  ]
})
```

export default router

Layout.vue

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <section class='main-section section'>
      <div class='container content'>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </section>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import AppHeader from './AppHeader.vue'
import AppFooter from './AppFooter.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    'app-header': AppHeader,
    'app-footer': AppFooter
  }
}
</script>
<style lang='scss'>
$primary: #287ab1;
@import '~bulma';

</style>
```

I am following this guy's code [Here](https://github.com/bstavroulakis/vue-spa) and his [course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/vue-js-single-page-applications/table-of-contents)

Comment: What happens when you change `...AppLayout` to `render: h => h(AppLayout)`?

Comment: @Daniel same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `Vue.use(VueRouter)` is not doing its thing...

This is likely due to case sensitivity with your Vue import.

```js
import Vue from 'Vue'  // <--- should be 'vue' NOT 'Vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Category from './theme/Category.vue'
import Login from './theme/Login.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/', component: Category},
    {path: '/login', component: Login}
  ]
})
```

Comment: spot on!, fresh set of eyes always helps, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Daniel: Why then `Vue.use()` did not cause an error?

Comment: I don't know ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯